# Does the kidney regulate sodium balance or total body sodium

Tags: physiology, kidney, renal-physiology

Imagine the following situation. You have a person who initially eats 10 mEq/day of salt. He then, at t=0 begins to eat 150 mEq/day of Na, and will continue to do so, because you're forcing them to, forever. My question is about how the kidney responds to such a situation. There's two options.

- Option #1: The Kidney ensures **sodium balance** (sodium intake = sodium excretion). In this situation, the kidney regulatory mechanisms ramp up Na excretion until it equals 150 mEq/day. But since this takes a couple of days, there is a bit of time in which intake > excretion and so total body Na rises. Because of osmoregulation, more water is drunk to balance the increased total body Na, and so the person's weight rises.
- Option #2: The Kidney brings **total body sodium** back to normal. In this situation, the kidney regulatory mechanisms ramp up Na excretion, but it briefly ramps up excretion to more than 150 mEq/day (excretion > intake) to excrete out the increase in total body sodium that built-up. In this case, the weight gain is temporary.

See a graph describing the two different responses.
[image]
The situation is inspired by Chapter 40 of Boron & Boulapep's Physiology textbook. The reason for the question is that Boron states that Option #1 is correct, whereas my teacher in class said differently  ¯_(ツ)_/¯ .

Comment: What specifically does your book and instructor say happens? I suspect they differ a bit from the scenarios you've crafted in ways that make them quite the same, instead of in conflict...

Comment: I phrased the question to my teacher exactly as I have done so here. I asked, assume you have a person and you have them increase their salt intake consistently - a hamburger every day is the example I used - what would happen to their weight: would it go up then down, or up and stay constant at the new high value.

Comment: And what does the book say?